# Almost always almost right

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, approximation-hardness

I am looking for a complexity class that relates to APX as BPP relates to P. I have already asked the same question [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19583/almost-always-almost-right), but perhaps TCS would be a more fruitful location for answers.

The reason for the question is that in practical problems one often needs to find approximate answers (thus APX) with sufficiently high confidence (thus BPP), which would make the class of problems with bounded probabilistic approximation algorithms potentially a useful model of what's computable in practice.

A possible candidate of such class would be $APX^{BPP}$: problems that admit approximated solutions with bounded probabilistic subroutines; however, I'm not confident that such class would be the appropriate setting for the class probabilistically computable approximations.

Both BPP and APX have been extensively studied. Is that the case for $APX^{BPP}$, or whichever class would be the best to capture the above problems?

Comment: BPP and P are decision problem classes. Maybe you should first ask what is the function/search class corresponding to BPP before moving to approximation, I think if we have the function/search class then the definition of its approximation version shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is the optimization version of PAC (Probably Approximately Correct) learning. Whereas the theory of PAC learning is specifically about (randomly, with high probably of correctness) learning *functions* to describe data, as in machine learning, you're asking about optimization problems. Still, maybe the PAC learning literature is a good place to start searching...

Comment: Rather than the oracle notation, what you are describing is closer to the BP operator. The BP operator is defined on complexity classes of decision problems. It should be easy to extend the definition to promise problems and define a promise problem version of your complexity class that way. Defining a version for optimization problems might be trickier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any given objective function, let BotL (best-of-the-list) be the algorithm that evaluates the objective function on a set of inputs and returns an input from that list that had maximal output (from among those inputs), with ties broken arbitrarily. $\:$ Since APX only includes problems

who's objective function can be computed in deterministic polynomial time, BotL can be implemented deterministically in polynomial time. $\:$ Furthermore, the value returned by BotL

is at least as good as any of inputs in the least that BotL was evaluated on. $\:$ In particular,

if any of the inputs in that list is good-enough then BotL's output will be good-enough.

Therefore running BotL on the outputs of a sufficiently large number of independent executions of a base algorithm can amplify the success probability from 1/poly to 1-(1/(2^poly)).

As consequence of the preceding paragraph, the precise

confidence level essentially does not affect the resulting class.

(This situation is highly analogous to [RP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RP_%28complexity%29).)

I was not able to find anything about that on the complexity zoo, although there

might have been talks on it given at the workshop referred to in [this paper](http://www.dcs.ed.ac.uk/home/mrj/RAND-APXworkshop/report.ps).

Comment: OP is asking for the name of the class of problems that have a randomized constant factor approximation algorithms. You are saying (I think) that the probability of success for such algorithms can be amplified. I am failing to see how this answers the question?

Comment: I don't see that question in the OP. $\:$ Michael is asking if the class has "been extensively studied". $\:$ Admittedly, I didn't have much to say about that, but I did (at least try to) address a misunderstanding about what such a class would be. $\;\;\;$

Comment: There is no such misunderstanding in the question.

Comment: Right. $\:$ The misunderstanding is in the "A possible candidate of such class would be ... probabilistically computable approximations." paragraph, which is in the post but not the question. $\;\;\;$

Comment: I do not see how the paragraph you mention contains any misunderstanding about being able to amplify probability of success.

Comment: The only randomness that would be involved in implementing an APX^BPP oracle machine would be the randomness used to simulate the oracle queries, and the accuracy of BPP algorithms can "obviously" (that is, in a very-easy-to-look-up way) be amplified. $\:$ Thus, it is comparatively easy to convert an APX^BPP machine to a (real) algorithm such that the probability of that algorithm's answer not being good enough is exponentially small. $\:$ (continued ...)

Comment: (... continued) $\:$ However, amplification for the randomized version of APX _critically depends on_ the fact that the objective functions can be computed efficiently. $\:$ Without that, one must choose how runtime is allowed to depend on the upper bound for the probability of producing an output that is not good enough, analogous to the difference between [PTASes, EPTASes, and FPTASes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_approximation_scheme#Variants). $\:$ (continued ...)

Comment: (... continued) $\:$ The fact that amplification actually is possible implies that all reasonable choices for the dependence (or even not requiring that the error-bound can be made arbitrarily small) capture the same problems. $\;\;\;$

Comment: With the clarifications, it's still my opinion that your answer is not correcting a misunderstanding in the OP, but just gives an arbitrary fact about randomized approximations.